# Trying to broadcast socket.io message to all connected sockets in e.g. room

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, broadcast

Challenge:

I would like to use **SailsJS**, and be able to join a room, by means of socket.io, and receive unsolicited messages from this room, not just when one enters or leaves the room but also receive objects.

So several clients connect to the server.
Afterwards broadcast (initiated from the server) messages/objects to every room and thus everey connected socket in this room.

I maybe could just send every connected socket a message, but dearly would like a example on how to do this with SailsJS 0.10, and a elegant method in the SailsJS 0.10 way.

I am looking at : https://github.com/balderdashy/sailsChat, but I think this is to close to the models themselves, with like e.g: autosubscribe: ['destroy', 'update']

In my opinion this should be more loosely coupled, and not so tied to the model itself.

Thanks in advance!

I.

Comment: I see this is almost the thing, but need more input ;) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101898/how-to-use-socketio-for-showing-online-offline-user-in-real-time-using-sails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the [SailsChat](https://github.com/balderdashy/sailsChat) example is to demonstrate how [Sails JS resourceful pubsub](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub) can take a lot of hassle out of socket messaging when you are mainly concerned with sending messages about models.  The fact that you can make a full-featured chat app in Sails with *very* little back-end code is what makes it impressive.  For situations where resourceful pubsub is not appropriate--or if you just plain don't want to use it--Sails exposes lower-level methods on the [`sails.sockets` namespace](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.sockets).  The docs are pretty clear on how they work.

To join a socket to an arbitrary room, do `sails.sockets.join(<socket>, <roomName>)`, where `<socket>` is either a raw socket (probably from `req.socket` or a socket ID).

To broadcast a message to all sockets in a room, do `sails.sockets.broadcast(<roomName>, <data>)`.

These and more methods are described in detail in the [Sails JS documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/websockets/sails.sockets).

Comment: Alright! Wauw! Is it possible and maybe even mandatory the 'room' is situated in persistent storage like redis in case of scaling up the nodejs app. Currently I am able to store sessions in redis (locally trough a vagrant instance) also, and has a relationship in config/sockets.js also pointing to the same redis storage.

Comment: In any way, I going to read and do more homework! (Y) I did a project with Red5 (java), and I'm searching a elegant way to utilize the sockets for epic applications :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking re: Redis; it sounds like you've already set up a Redis socket store (good job!), so clearly the answer is yes.

Comment: Indeed, it was a bit off topic. At the moment exploring the possibilities and determine the big picture. Next step will be binding users to a collection of socket ids. But we'll create another topic when necessary. Thanks for the eye opener!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting with SailsJS, and already a big fan.
I need to find out if this is also scalable with e.g. Heroku or other flavors of SAAS providers, but seems not that hard.

So just a follow up on what I did with SailsJS 0.10:

**Server-side:**

Made a controller with the following:

```
join: function (req, res) {

  if (req.isSocket === true) {

    sails.sockets.join(req.socket, 'mysecretroom');
    return res.send(200, 'joined');

  }

  return res.send(200);

},
sendToRoom: function( req, res ) {
  if (req.isSocket === true ) {
     sails.sockets.broadcast('mysecretroom', 'messageevent', {message:'Listen very carefully, I'll shall say this only once..!'});
  }
  return res.send(200);
}
```

**Client-side:**

```
io.socket.on('messageevent', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
})
```

+1 kudos @sgress454!

Thanks!